# Why is assigning whole Blender array so much faster than assigning through iteration?

Tags: python, performance, blender

I have two functions that both generate random noise but one of them takes several seconds to accomplish and another runs in miliseconds. On the hardware level, where does the difference come from? When I use the second function, are instructions executed in parallel? or is the whole array in memory moved to the corresponding memory array where the image is stored?
    from random import random

```
def slow_random():
    for i in range(len(bpy.data.images['img'].pixels)):# < pixels are just a list of pixesl color values, where 0 <= value <= 1
        bpy.data.images['img'].pixels[i] = random()

def quick_random():
    rand = [random() for i in range(len(bpy.data.images['img'].pixels))]
    bpy.data.images['img'].pixels[0:] = rand
```

Here's a [link](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51466) to my blend file. I don't know whether it's safe. I can post a similar question on BlenderStack and upload a file there only in 1.5 hours. download, unpack, and launch blender from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/) (takes minutes). Open the file, in the script window, you can press Alt+P to run it. Uncomment functions at the end of the list. The slow function is going to simply freeze the application.

I think, @cephner is right in saying that this is due to the implementation of the `__setitem__` method. Because it must access the pixel, change its value, and redraw it.

Comment: Are you sure you are running tests in the proper conditions? These two should take approximately the same time. You should provide your test code too.

Comment: @cglacet do it in a moment. it's in blender though. I don't use python anywhere else... I attach the Blender file and the script

Comment: The time to generate the random values is the same. However, depending on the type of the `pixels` attribute, I can imagine that a single slice assignment could be faster than assigning to each element individually. `slow_random` has to call the type's `__setitem__`  method `n` times; `quick_random` only has to call it once.

Comment: @cephner `type(bpy.data.images['Untitled'].pixels)
<class 'bpy_prop_array'>` if I understand correctly, the developers of the class have defined __setitem__ to set individual pixels or all pixels at once? I mean, there are two distinct C implementations of the `__setitme__` method depending on context? and `__setitem__` for the whole array is superfast?

Comment: Then you should ask a question about this type `bpy_prop_array` because this is somewhat unrelated to python (as this class can implement anything and cause this code to be super slow).

Comment: @cglacet agree, I didn't think about it in the first place.I try to find out and make edits or delete the question

Comment: It seems to be some blender specific type, I can't find the source code of it yet.

Comment: @cglacet exactly, don't waste your time. its definition is somewhere in Blender's source code. but if you are really, really interested, here are instructions how to download source and build https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows

Comment: sorry, I just didn't think that it's not python-related before cephner has pointed out

Comment: At least you know that one way is faster than the other, but if as you suggested there is some kind of observer that update a drawing everytime a pixel is changing then that would be quite logical for your second code to be extremely slow. If you don't find this in the documentation that's worth asking the devs on some clarifications.

Comment: @cglacet yeah, I think it's either redrawing or updating the state of Blender because a property 'was changed'. and does so for each pixel. yes, I'll try to ask devs and make an update